# Reading and passing element innerhtml to controller using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Greeting!

I'm trying to figure out if there is some way to pass an innerHTML from let's say a div element to a controller action using Ajax.

Is there somebody who know a nice fix for this? I thought something like this might work, but it does not since the function "does not exist in the current context":

```
 <div id ="value">Foo value</div>

  @Ajax.ActionLink("Try me", 
                   "MyAction", 
                   "MyController", 
                   new { value = GetValue() }, 
                   new AjaxOptions{}
                 )
```

and a function which reads the innerhtml, kinda like this:

```
 function GetValue() 
 {
    return $('#value').html();
 }
```

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: why not assigning a class to your `ActionLink` and then updating its value on `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean or if we're on the same page, care to elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it with an actionlink. You'll need to put the Ajax function in script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/MyAction',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { value: GetValue() },
    cache: false
})
.done(function(result) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Just for background: The reason the OP's code doesn't work is because `ActionLink` runs server-side, while `GetValue()` runs client-side, long after the server is already done.